# Clickbank API in php?

Tags: php, api, curl, clickbank

i need to get digital products from click bank, so am using their API to get products, unfortunately given example code given by them are not working, am using CURL to do this ,

code is below :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/products/list");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/xml", "Authorization:DEV-KEY:API-KEY"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print $result;

?>
```

but i got the below error

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2013 05:20:47 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.23 (FreeBSD) mod_jk/1.2.37 mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8x Vary: Accept-Encoding Connection: close Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/plain The API call (/api/rest/1.3/products/list) requires parameters which are missing : [site]1
```

have any one got this error before ?

Comment: Are you aware that you posted your access credentials publicly on the internet?

Answer (score 2):

It's expecting a parameter called site. Please see the docs here: 
https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/products

Comment: Thank you so much, what is mean by site here? can you clear me?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/products/list?site=<your unique affiliate id>");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/xml", "Authorization:DEV-KEY:API-KEY"));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    print $result;

    ?>
```